# Difference between turns function and winding function PMSM?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, induction-motor, pmsm

What is the difference between turns function and winding function as applied in the Modified Winding Theory and how do I compute them given the parameters of a PMSM?

Answer (score 0):

Winding function is turns function without an average value.

[How?](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/tee.20117)